# Plotting side-by-side stacked bar charts in plotly from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have the following dataframe:

```
Position   Tenure  Location  Concept
a          0-3     d          Y  
a          4-7     e          N
b          4-7     f          M 
c          8-11    d          M
d          0-3     g          Y
b          12-14   f          N
```

What I want is a side-by-side stacked plotly bar chart of Position, Tenure and Location per concept. e.g. For Concept Y I want a bar chart of position (height of 2, stacked a and d) next to a chart for Tenure (height of 2, in this case will only have 0-3) and a chart of Location (height of 2, 1 for d and 1 for g here).

Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd like to have a grouped and stacked bar chart, and as far as I know that [is not available at the moment](https://community.plot.ly/t/combination-of-grouped-and-stacked-bar-chart/2154). But when it comes to grouping and visualizing all facets of your particular dataframe, plotly has other flexible options within the arguments of `px.Bar()`:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# data input
df = pd.DataFrame({'Position': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'b'},
                     'Tenure': {0: '0-3', 1: '4-7', 2: '4-7', 3: '8-11', 4: '0-3', 5: '12-14'},
                     'Location': {0: 'd', 1: 'e', 2: 'f', 3: 'd', 4: 'g', 5: 'f'},
                     'Concept': {0: 'Y', 1: 'N', 2: 'M', 3: 'M', 4: 'Y', 5: 'N'}})
# plotly express
fig = px.bar(df, x="Concept", y="Tenure", color="Tenure", barmode="group",
            facet_col="Location",color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.diverging.Spectral[-2::-1])

# Remove duplicate x-axis names:
for axis in fig.layout:
    if type(fig.layout[axis]) == go.layout.XAxis:
        fig.layout[axis].title.text = ''

fig['layout']['xaxis2']['title']['text']='Concept'

fig.show()
```